# cordova-plugin-googlemaps Camera Speed Slow

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, google-maps-api-3

How do I adjust animation speed of camera?

It doesn't feel like lag or anything, it just animates slowly.

There is no mention of this in tutorial or anywhere else

```
map.animateCamera({
    target: {
        lat: "100",
        lng: "100",
        speed: 10 //I tried adding this, it doesn't do anything
    },
    zoom: 15
});
```

Tutorial: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging around I found the solution in the tutorial barely visible. I don't think you can find unless you look hard. Anyways, here it is

```
map.animateCamera({
    target: {
        lat: "100",
        lng: "100"
    },
    zoom: 15,
    duration: 1000 //Camera Animation speed in milliseconds
});
```